# Picking (pick_event) the correct artist on tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to use the pick_event in matplotlib within the tkinter framework. I have a problem with picking the right artist on the plot. I have multiple annotated artist on the plots with arrows connecting the annotated points, and I am trying to move the annotations around because they overlap and are not readable. I can move them in some cases with mouse_motion without any issues. The problem is sometimes clicking an artist generates event from an earlier moved artist and then the older artist starts moving and I can see in my pick_event function that indeed the older artist was the one that generated the last event. Sometimes 3 artists produce events on clicking sometimes more, irrespective of their positions on the graph. How can I make sure to only move the artist which is clicked? I know their is a hierarchy in pick_event. **Can somebody show me a snippet where annotations can be picked correctly?** I assume when annotations are close by there can be a confusion as to which one is clicked but if the annotations are far away from each other they should be distinguishable.

Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: You have a problem with your code. But without there being a [mcve] of the issue, nobody can know what problem there is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. I will try to add a minimal example. I have separate it from the rest of the code. Thanks.